# How to extend HTML elements with Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, custom-controls, web-component

I try to create custom button in Angular 7. This button should support all attributes, which already have standard HTML button, like autofocus, disabled and etc. So I try to extend `HTMLButtonElement` in my component like this:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class ButtonComponent extends HTMLButtonElement {
}
```

But I get error message `Error: Failed to construct 'HTMLButtonElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Is some way to extend HTML element in Angular component without using directive?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-extend-html-element?file=src/app/button.component.ts)

Comment: why not use as template some like `template: '<button><ng-content></ng-content></button>'`?

Comment: @Eliseo, see the issue I linked to in my answer to see why one may want to extend a native element. In short, if you wish to make your component behave the same as the native element you added to your component template, then you need to "proxy" all the native element's events. For example, a button emits a `focus` event when it's focused. If you want users of your component to be able to bind to that event, you need to expose it as an `@Output`. If Angular components could extend native elements, then assumingly native events would be exposed for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular components are not able to extend native elements. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19108) on the Angular repo regarding this topic. Today you need to have your Angular component wrap the native HTML element, i.e you need to add the native element in your component template.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I subscribed on Angular issue.